Show that rank of a system of vectors equals the rank of the coordinate matrix of that vector system

Let $S = \{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_m\}$ be a system of vectors in an
$n$-dimensional vector space $V$ with basis $\mathcal{B} = \{e_1, e_2,
 \dots, e_n\}$. Let $A$ be the coordinate matrix of $S$ with respect to
basis $\mathcal{B}$. Show that $\text{rank}(S) = \text{rank}(A)$.

In the text I am using, the rank of a vector system is defined as the greatest number of linearly independent vectors in the system, while the rank of a matrix is the greatest order of its minor whose value is nonzero. I struggled to connect these two definitions, which reflects my difficulty in understanding the relationship between matrices and vectors.
For context, my linear algebra class (for CS major) is structured as follows:

Early chapters focus on matrices: matrix operations, determinants, inverse matrices, matrix rank, and solving linear systems.

Later chapters introduce vector spaces, subspaces, basis, and linear dependence, often using matrices to represent and manipulate vectors.


When we move to vector spaces, matrices are frequently used as tools to operate on vectors, but I don’t fully understand why matrices work the way they do. It feels like there’s a disconnect: the concepts from the matrix-focused chapters seem like their own self-contained "world," while the vector-space chapters feel like a fresh start, though they happen to use matrices in ways that seem somewhat magical or arbitrary.
Any insights into the connection between these two worlds would be greatly appreciated, though my primary goal is to understand this specific result.
Thank you!

Let $k = rank(S)$ and $l = rank(A)$. Up to a reordering of the vectors in $S$, we can suppose that $v_1, \dots, v_k$ are linearly independent. This amounts to saying that the null space of the matrix
$$
M  = [ v_1 \ v_2 \dots v_k]
$$
contains only the zero vector. Hence,  the reduced row echelon form (RREF) of M is the $n \times k$ block matrix
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
I_k \\ 
0
\end{array} 
\right]
$$
Therefore, the minor obtained selecting the entries of the first $k$ rows and columns of $A$ is non-zero. Then, $rank(S) \le rank(A)$.
Since $l = rank(A)$,  there exists a non-zero minor obtained selecting the entries of $l$ columns of $A$. Up to a reordering of the vectors in $S$ and of the basis vectors, we can suppose that such a minor is the determinant of the upper left corner of the matrix $A$. If we compute the RREF of the matrix
$$
[v_1 \ v_2 \dots v_l]
$$
we get the $n \times l$ block matrix
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
I_l \\ 
0
\end{array} 
\right]
$$
Therefore $rank(A) \le rank(S)$. We can conclude that $rank(S) =rank(A)$.
